# unable to import 'ag-grid-react' in a PReact Project

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, preact, ag-grid-react

I am importing AgGridReact in my project like this: 
`import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';`. 
Although, the libraries are present, the lint keeps on showing me the following error: `JSX element type 'AgGridReact' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.`

---

My Versions are:

> "ag-grid": "^17.1.1",
>       "ag-grid-react": "^17.1.0"

Comment: How do you use it in your component?

Comment: `<AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}>
        </AgGridReact>`

Comment: @kiarashws if you have a solution could you share it, I am facing the same issue